# Javascript Canvas clearRect method problems

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have 2 balls in game enemy and Player whenever i want to change coordinates i clear player rect but for some reasons enemy disappears. Does anyone have some tips what to do? maybe it's because i'm doing wrong making functions moveleft moveright.if you also see something bad with code please provide tips.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var Player1 = {
  x: 150,
  y: 70,
  velX: 20,
  velY: 12,
  hp: 20,
  startAngle: 40,
};
var Enemy = {
  x: 200,
  y: 150,
  velX: 12,
  velY: 12,
  hp: 20,
  startAngle: 40,
};

function drawPlayer1() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(Player1.x, Player1.y, Player1.startAngle, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawEnemy() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(Enemy.x, Enemy.y, Enemy.startAngle, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function move(event) {
  // the event.keyCode is Deprecated, use event.code or event.key
  if (event.keyCode == '39' || event.key === ' ') {

    if (Player1.x < c.width - Player1.startAngle) {
      updatePositionRight();
    }
  }
  if (event.keyCode == '37' || event.key == ' ') {

    if (Player1.x > 0 + Player1.startAngle) {
      updatePositionLeft();
    }

  }
  if (event.keyCode == '38' || event.key == ' ') {
    if (Player1.y > 0 + Player1.startAngle) {
      updatePositionUp();
    }

  }
  if (event.keyCode == '40' || event.key == ' ') {

    if (Player1.y < c.height - Player1.startAngle) {
      updatePositionDown();
    }
  }
}

function updatePositionRight() {

  // update Player1's property
  Player1.x += Player1.velX;

  // erase the canva
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // redraw Player1
  drawPlayer1();
}

function updatePositionLeft() {

  // update Player1's property
  Player1.x -= Player1.velX;

  // erase the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // redraw Player1
  drawPlayer1();
}

function updatePositionDown() {

  // update Player1's property
  Player1.y += Player1.velY;

  // erase the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // redraw Player1
  drawPlayer1();
}

function updatePositionUp() {

  // update Player1's property
  Player1.y -= Player1.velY;

  // erase the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // redraw Player1
  drawPlayer1();
}
// bind event
window.addEventListener('keydown', move, false);
// initialize
function drawEntities() {
  drawPlayer1();
  drawEnemy();
}
drawEntities();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: call drawEntities instead of drawPlayer1 in update functions

Answer (score 2):

You also need to redraw your `enemy` with every `updatePositionXXX` function. Currently only `player1` is being redrawn after `clearRect` calls.

Comment: is it wrong redrawing enemy in every updatepos of player1?

Comment: The reason why this is needed is because the clearRect is clearing the entire canvas so both the player, enemy and anything else on the canvas needs to be re-drawn.